# $E$ a full subcategory of $E'$, functors $K,L: D \rightarrow E,$ with $J: E \rightarrow E'$ inclusion, prove that Nat$(K,L) \cong $ Nat$(JK, JL)$

Tags: category-theory

> $E$ a full subcategory of $E'$, functors $K,L: D \rightarrow E,$ with $J: E \rightarrow E'$ inclusion, prove that Nat$(K,L) \cong $ Nat$(JK, JL)$

I can see that I need to show that there's a bijection between these two set.  I would guess that $\alpha: K \rightarrow L \mapsto J\alpha : JK \rightarrow JL$ would be one map, but I'm having trouble finding the inverse.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You’ll want to look at the definition of a full subcategory, and what sort of relationship there must be between $E(X,Y)$ and $E’(X, Y)$.